# Prolog, Why does my predicate print the output of `write()` multiple times?

Tags: prolog

I having a hard time understand what my predicate `fly(....)` is outputting. When I consult this file and ask the console(SWI-Prolog) `flight(city1, city2, A, B)` it prints out `A=9 B=10`. Which I was figuring is a single value for A and B alike. So I then wanted to use the output to finish what I was trying to accomplish; flight planner. But it seems that when I use the same question (`flight(city1, city2, A, B)`) in a predicate it returns a list. I did not realize this until I tried to write `S` and/or `E`. I am printing `[1,2,3]` in the code below because I was confused why when I only wrote `S`, and not anything after it, the output was just each value in the list not comma or space separated. So I decided to see how it would write a explicitly defined a list `[1,2,3]` and printed it.

The output I am receiving

```
8 ?- fly(city1, city4, 0, 24).
   14[1,2,3]9[1,2,3]
   false.
```

It seems like the line `write(S), write([1,2,3]),` is being called twice, why is this?

Also, why do I get a single value in the console for `A` and `B` but not in my predicate when it is called?

Code verbatim:

```
% I have no idea what I'm doing.
% Author: Skeeter

% Total of 5 cities
city(city1).
city(city2).
city(city3).
city(city4).
city(city5).

% List of flights
% flight( StartCity, EndCity, DepartureTime, ArrivalTime)
% city1 departures
flight( city1, city2, 09, 10).
flight( city1, city2, 10, 11).
flight( city1, city3, 12, 13).
flight( city1, city4, 14, 15).
flight( city1, city5, 16, 17).
% city2 departures
flight( city2, city1, 09, 10).
flight( city2, city1, 10, 11).
flight( city2, city3, 12, 13).
flight( city2, city4, 14, 15).
flight( city2, city5, 16, 17).
% city3 departures
flight( city3, city1, 09, 10).
flight( city3, city2, 10, 11).
flight( city3, city2, 12, 13).
flight( city3, city4, 14, 15).
flight( city3, city5, 16, 17).
% city4 departures
flight( city4, city1, 09, 10).
flight( city4, city2, 10, 11).
flight( city4, city3, 12, 13).
flight( city4, city3, 14, 15).
flight( city4, city5, 16, 17).
% city5 departures
flight( city5, city1, 09, 10).
flight( city5, city2, 10, 11).
flight( city5, city3, 12, 13).
flight( city5, city4, 14, 15).
flight( city5, city4, 16, 17).

% city1 arrivals
flight( city2, city1, 09, 10).
flight( city2, city1, 10, 11).
flight( city3, city1, 12, 13).
flight( city4, city1, 14, 15).
flight( city5, city1, 16, 17).
% city2 arrivals
flight( city1, city2, 09, 10).
flight( city1, city2, 10, 11).
flight( city3, city2, 12, 13).
flight( city4, city2, 14, 15).
flight( city5, city2, 16, 17).
% city3 arrivals
flight( city1, city3, 09, 10).
flight( city2, city3, 10, 11).
flight( city2, city3, 12, 13).
flight( city4, city3, 14, 15).
flight( city5, city3, 16, 17).
% city4 arrivals
flight( city1, city4, 09, 10).
flight( city2, city4, 10, 11).
flight( city3, city4, 12, 13).
flight( city3, city4, 14, 15).
flight( city5, city4, 16, 17).
% city5 arrivals
flight( city1, city5, 09, 10).
flight( city2, city5, 10, 11).
flight( city3, city5, 12, 13).
flight( city4, city5, 14, 15).
flight( city4, city5, 16, 17).

% is H1 later than X?
isLater(H1, [X|Y]) :-
H1 > X.


fly(CityFrom, CityTo, StartTime, EndTime) :-
flight(CityFrom, CityTo, S, E),
write(S), write([1,2,3]),
isLater(StartTime, S),
isLater(EndTime, E).
```

Comment: Why is the second argument to `isLater` a list?

Comment: At one point I had figured S was a list, I didn't realize prolog backtracks as it does when it executes.

Comment: If you pass something that is not a list, it will mismatch, fail, and backtrack. In this case, you have only one `isLater` clause so it simply fails (there's nothing to backtrack to). You could allow list and non-list cases by adding clauses for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program flow inside `fly(city1, city2, A, B)` goes like this:

- Call `flight(city1, city2, S, E)`. This comes back with `S=9`, `E=10`.
- Call `write(9)`.
- Call `isLater(A, 9)`. This fails, because `9` can't be unified with `[X|Y]`, and triggers a backtrack.
- Backtrack to `flight(city1, city2, S, E)`. This time it returns with `S=10`, `E=11`.
- Call `write(10)`.
- Again, `isLater(A, 10)` fails. It can't backtrack any more, since it's tried every alternative for `flight(city1, city2, _, _)`, so at this point, `fly` fails.

Basically, the problem is that you're writing `S` before you've decided it's a valid solution, so you end up printing a bunch of non-solutions as well. You probably want to move it after your `isLater` checks. (The bigger issue here is that `isLater` is expecting a list, but you're giving it an integer...)

Note that typing `flight(city1, city2, A, B).` in the console will also return multiple values - after it shows you the first solution, just press ";" (instead of the enter key) to ask for the next one.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize I had to hit (in my case space) ";" for more output from the console. It made a whole lot more sense when I figured that out. Thanks for the response too, it clears it up for me.